# Show blogpost suitable to the current category

Tags: python, django

I want to filter my database based on the menuItem or category of my blog posts.
With self.request.path I get something like '/py/' what represents one of my categories.

By now I do this way and it works fine, but is there a better way?
Should I create for each category a different app and write it's own IndexView with fix queryset filter?
If there is a better solution to my problem than I would happy to know :)

Here my CategoryIndexView:

```html
class CategoryIndexView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/category_index.html'
    # context_object_name = 'category'

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = self.request.path[1:-1]
        if category.lower() == 'ml':
            query_set = Post.objects.filter(category=0)
        elif category.lower() == 'py':
            query_set = Post.objects.filter(category=1)
        elif category.lower() == 'kt':  
            query_set = Post.objects.filter(category=2) 
        elif category.lower() == 'cpp':
            query_set = Post.objects.filter(category=3)
        else: 
            query_set = Post.objects.filter(category=0)
        return query_set
```

Here a snippet of my urlpatterns:

```html
urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', genViews.about, name='about'),
    path('imprint/', genViews.imprint, name='imprint'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',genViews.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'), 
    path('ml/',blogViews.CategoryIndexView.as_view(), name='machine_learning'),
    path('py/',blogViews.CategoryIndexView.as_view(), name='python'),
    path('kt/',blogViews.CategoryIndexView.as_view(), name='android'),
    path('cpp/',blogViews.CategoryIndexView.as_view(), name='cpp')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way yes, try adding a parameter to the url, like so:

**urls.py**

```py
...
    path("posts/<category>/", views.posts, name="posts"),
...
```

**views.py**

```py
def posts(request, category):
    query_set = Post.objects.filter(category=0)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's is a more efficient way of getting it done. I'd suggest that you use only one view to handle and `filter` the `queryset` based on the `category` clicked on.  For example:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
     # other URLs 
     path('categories/<str:category>/',blogViews.CategoryIndexView.as_view(), name='categories'),
     
     # [ <str:category> ] accepting the category the user clicks on to filter the database 
]
```

**views.py**

```
class CategoryIndexView(ListView):
     model = Post
     template_name = 'blog/category_index.html'
     # context_object_name = 'category'

     def get_queryset(self):
         # Using kwargs.get() to capture the category passed via the url
         category = self.kwargs.get('category', None)  

         queryset = Post.objects.filter(category__iexact=category)

         # If your category field is a FK field then use 
         # queryset = Post.objects.filter(category__name__iexact=category)

         return queryset
```